# Where to check whether a instruction is for ring0 or ring3

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, instrumentation, instructions

I need to check whether instruction `BNDSTX` (a new instruction added by Intel MPX extension) can run in ring3, or it's for ring0 exclusively. I believe that [Intel ISA extension manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/0d/53/319433-022.pdf) should contains all information I need, but I didn't find privilege information there.

Am I looking at wrong place, or I overlooked it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be listed in the `protected mode exceptions` section. Found no example of this in the given manual, but the normal instruction set reference does have a few:

> #GP(0) If the current privilege level is not 0.

Also, section *9.3 INTEL MPX PROGRAMMING MODEL* says:

> Intel MPX allows an OS to support user mode software (operating at
>   CPL=3) and supervisor mode software (CPL < 3) to add memory protection
>   capability against buffer overrun.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Does these two points mean this instruction _can_ run in ring3, yes?

Comment: Intel had an intro-to-MPX article I remember reading that said it was designed so the kernel and user-space processes could both be using MPX independently, to check themselves.  This would entail a bound-register save/restore.